# Find consecutively increasing numbers in subarray C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am currently working on finding at least 4 and 5 consecutive numbers (such as {3, 4, 5, 6} and {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}) in one row of a 2D array.

For example, if you were given a 2D array like this:

```
int arr[3][5] = {{3, 4, 6, 1, 1}, {6, 3, 4, 5, 1}, {6, 1, 2, 3, 3}};
```

How would you go about testing if only the subarray {6, 3, 4, 5, 1} has at least 4 consecutive numbers?

Here is what I considered at first (please note that I am new to C++):

```
int lowerStraight(int arr[][5]) {

    //lower straight code
    int lowerStraightSum = 0;
    int minNum, nextNum, threeNum, fourNum;
    minNum = findMin(arr);
    nextNum = minNum + 1;
    threeNum = nextNum + 1;
    fourNum = threeNum + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (arr[1][i] == nextNum) {
            if (arr[1][i] == threeNum) {
                if (arr[1][i] == fourNum) {
                    lowerStraightSum = 30;
            }
        }
    }
}
cout << lowerStraightSum;
return lowerStraightSum; }
```

The code above prints 0 even if the array has 4 or more consecutive numbers. Plus, it assumes that the minimum number is where the consecutive numbers start, which may not be the case. Any advice on both of these things is appreciated.

Comment: Implement the solution for a single dimension array.  Then all you would need to do is call the single-dimension array solution in a `for` loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Are you saying to copy that particular subarray to a 1D array? Could you please show me how to go about that? Also, what could I alter about the code itself to get my desired output?

Comment: What I'm saying is that each of those sub arrays are one-dimensional arrays.  You know how many rows there are, so just loop on the rows: `for (int i = 0; i < number_of_rows; ++i) { if (isconsecutive(arr[i])) { found it } }`.  The `isconsecutive` function would be the function that works with a single row.  You now have to write the function `isconsecutive` (maybe add a parameter to tell you the number of items in the row), regardless of whether it is a 2D array or not.  Once you get that function to work, then the entire program works.

Answer (score 0):

The code below:

- walks an input matrix of `int`s;
- for each subarray, calls a `longest_sequence` method to find the longest sequence of consecutive numbers, and
- print that subarray if the sequence is equals to or bigger than `4`.

It uses:

- a range-based for loop to get each subarray from the matrix,
- `std::ranges::sort` to sort the array,
- `std::max` to compare the current longest sequence to the, until now, longest sequence.

You should not need the `template`d code if you are always going to work with subarrays of length `5`.

It doesn't claim to be the fastest method, since it does a sort and then a walk, but it's simple enough.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9v3h1TEGv)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // max, sort
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <ostream>

template <size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, int (&arr)[N])
{
    os << "{ ";
    bool first{true};
    for (int i : arr)
    {
        os << (first ? "" : ", ") << i;
        first = false;
    }
    return os << " }";
}

template <size_t N>
size_t longest_sequence(int (&arr)[N])
{
    if (N == 0) { return 0; }
    std::ranges::sort(arr);
    size_t max_sequence_length{1};
    size_t current_sequence_length{1};
    for (size_t i{1}; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i-1] + 1)
        {
            current_sequence_length++;
        }
        else
        {
            max_sequence_length = std::max(max_sequence_length, current_sequence_length);
            current_sequence_length = 1;
        }
    }
    max_sequence_length = std::max(max_sequence_length, current_sequence_length);
    return max_sequence_length;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[3][5] = {{3, 4, 6, 1, 1}, {6, 3, 4, 5, 1}, {6, 1, 2, 3, 3}};
    for (auto& subarr : arr)
    {
        if (longest_sequence(subarr) >= 4)
        {
            std::cout << subarr << "\n";
        }
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//    { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will help you to split the big problem into more smaller problems. Make a function for the smaller problem and call it from an "above" to solve the bigger problem.

So let us first forget about many rows in a 2 dimansional matrix, but just on one row. One row is a simple array.

And the we analyze the requirement "consecutive numbers". Somthing like, 4,5,6,7,8.

If we look at these numbers, then we find out that main property of such a sequence is that the delta between one number and another number is 1.

So, looking at the array "90, 80, 70, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 60, 50, 40" we could iterate over the array and check if a "number - the previous number" is 1.

Then we can count, how many times we get a delta of one. For this we can use a counter. Because we look at sequences with 4 or 5 elements, we can compare the counter with 4 or 5. If the counter is below 4 or 5, and the delta is not 1, then we reset the counter and count again, if we find more consecutive numbers.

Your statement "at least 4 and 5" implies, that also longer sequences are OK. But it is a little bit ambigous. Because we then would not need to look at 5. Just >= 4 would be sufficient.

But this can be dealt with easily.

There are really many possible implementations.

Here is one of them in easy words

```
#include <iostream>

// Specify matrix size
const int NumberOfRows = 5;
const int NumberOfColumns = 5;

// Define some test data
int arr[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns] = { 
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {3, 4, 6, 1, 1},
    {6, 3, 4, 5, 1}, 
    {6, 1, 2, 3, 3},
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 6},
};

// Calculate max Number of consecutives in one row
int consecutives(int row[NumberOfColumns]) {

    // Here we will store the result
    int maxConsecutives = 0;

    // Current consecutives
    int consecutiveCounter = 1;

    // Check deltas
    for (int column = 1; column < NumberOfColumns; ++column) {
        if ((row[column] - row[column - 1]) == 1) {

            // We found a consecutive. Increment counter
            ++consecutiveCounter;
        }
        else {
            // This value is not a consecutive one.
            // Save the max value of consectutive values
            if (consecutiveCounter > maxConsecutives)

                // Save new max value
                maxConsecutives = consecutiveCounter;

            consecutiveCounter = 1;
        }
    }
    if (consecutiveCounter > maxConsecutives)

        // Save new max value
        maxConsecutives = consecutiveCounter;
    return maxConsecutives;
}
int main() {
    for (int row = 0; row < NumberOfRows; ++row) {

        int con = consecutives(arr[row]);

        if (con >= 4)
            std::cout << "Row " << row << " has at least " << con << " consecutives\n";
    }
}
```